# How to export multiple excel columns into a text file without a tab indentation using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to export two columns into a text file. I've written the following code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim saveFile As String
//Some code for selecting the range

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste

//Code for saving the file in *.txt
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

After saving the file. The rows in two columns are getting pasted as Tab separated. Is there any way I can paste them without any indentation?

As mentioned in one of the answers, if File format is `xlCSV` , I will get a file with Comma Separated Values. Similarly, I'd like to know how to get a `":"` separated columns.

Comment: Please share the code you have used to save as txt file. Thanks

Comment: @Alok Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each line and concatenate the two columns before saving.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim saveFile As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range

//Some code for selecting the range

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy

Set sh = wb.Worksheets(1)
sh.Paste

For Each rw In sh.Rows
  If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If

  rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = Concat(rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value, rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value)
  rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = ""
Next rw

//Code for saving the file in *.txt
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I don't want the columns to be separated with any indentation or ":" separated will also be fine.

Comment: Could you give an example of some output? Do you have white-space within your cells on the original workbook?

Comment: I don't have white spaces. They are just two columns. Let's say ABC and 111 are two values of cells in adjacent columns, I'd need the text file to have ABC111 instead of ABC   (Tab separated)  111

Comment: That makes sense, in that case, you might want to use the `CONCAT` function.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please brief it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've slightly modified your code `rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value & rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value` and it's still giving tab separation in some rows and no separation in rest of the rows.

Comment: In that case you might want to use `TRIM` for both cells: `rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = Trim(rw.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value) & Trim(rw.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value)` to get rid of white-space.

Comment: I did that, there is no change in output.

Comment: If there aren't that many files then it may be worth using a text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and doing a search and replace for white-space. Otherwise, I can't help you.